# Why can't template destructors be referenced and deleted?

Tags: c++, c++11, unions

I'm trying  to use template class to create `Vector3`.

My header file `vector.h` defining the `Vector3` struct:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Vector3 {
  union {
    struct {
      T x, y, z
    } xyz;
    std::vector<T> values;
  };

  Vector3() : values(3, 0) {}
  Vector3(T x, T y, T z) : xyz{x, y, z} {}
};
```

But when I use this struct with specified type `int`, I met the error:

> function "Vector3::~Vector3() [with T=int]" (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

I just use it by single line: `Vector3<int> vertex;`.

Total code:
I want to read Wavefront.obj file:
model.h:

```cpp
class ObjModel {
 private:
  std::vector<Vector3<int>> vertices;

 public:
  explicit ObjModel(const std::string& filename);
};
```

model.cpp:

```cpp
ObjModel::ObjModel(const std::string& filename) : vertices() {
  std::ifstream in;
  in.open(filename.c_str());
  std::string line;
  while (std::getline(in, line)) {
    if (line.empty() || '#' == line[0]) continue;
    if ('v' == line[0]) {
      std::istringstream iss(line);
      iss.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ' ');
      Vector3<int> vertex; **// here has problem**
      int i = 0;
      while (iss && 3 > i) {
        iss >> vertex.values[i];
        ++i;
      }
      vertices.push_back(vertex);
    } 
  }
}
```

The line `Vector3<int> vertex` gave the error.

I think the destructor should be default and don't know why it is deleted. I also tried to explicit declare it by adding the following code in `vector.h`:

```cpp
struct Vector3{
  ...
  ~Vector3() = default;
  ...
}
```

But it didn't work. Anyone can help me?

Comment: This just isn't going to work. `T values[3]` instead of `std::vector` *could* work, but even then it would be UB, I believe.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Sorry. Because many people said C++ now should use `std::vector` rather than array, is it wrong? And I don't know what UB means

Comment: UB means [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), aka breaking certain rules of the language, which can (formally) have any effect: the program can break in various ways, or it can continue working as if nothing happened, depending on your luck, compiler, and more.

Comment: *"many people said C++ now should use std::vector rather than array"* The same people should've told you to avoid unions when possible.

Comment: The synthesized destructor is deleted because the compiler cannot figure out if it needs to destruct the `xyz` or `values`.  You'll need to write your own destructor that incorporates your knowledge of which union member needs to be deleted.

Comment: *is it wrong?* - If you're dealing with an array whose size is known at compile-time, it is most likely wrong. Use `std::array` instead. Also note that punning via unions is UB in C++. You either use one member of a union or another - you can't write to `xyz` and then read `values`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, `T values[3]` _would_ work, because of the alignment guarantees the compiler must give regarding structure members and arrays. However, that makes still makes the code bad practice.

Comment: @Emmef Reading inactive union members is UB, regardless of alignment. GCC is documented to ignore this UB (and I think other modern compilers too), but it's still UB.

Comment: Ditch the union and `xyz`. You don't need them. Use `sts::array` (not vector) as a container for your coordinates.

Comment: ...and make `x`,`y`,`z` member functions, if you need them.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks a lot. I overload the operator[] to get value by index instead of using union. Thanks for your teaching about union and UB.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a **[union](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union)**, you MUST know the exact implementation and memory layout of the types that you "union", or you get undefined behaviour (UB). If you use anything different than [Plain Old Data](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType), things quickly get confusing.

And yes, since C++11 you can specify a specific constructor or undelete the `values` one. But realise this adds a lot of cognitive load for yourself and anyone reading your code. However, in your example with a vector, a specific constructor won't help you a bit. A vector is *dynamically allocated*, and must at least contain two variables: a pointer to allocated memory and a length. These share memory with the `xyz` values. In other words: writing a value to any of the `xyz` members destroys the vector's bookkeeping! This leads to all kinds of mayhem, including memory access violations and memory leaks. Just don't.

Apart from that, the values accessed via `values[index]` are in a dynamically allocated piece of memory and *do not* share the same memory as `xyz`. So don't expect that values[0] corresponds to `xyz.x`, even if you don't get a memory access violation.

Comment: I get it now, thanks! But I'm confused that you say std::vector is dynamically allocated so you mean I have to delete the vector manually in destructor? But I'm told that only vector<pointer> should be deleted manually.. So if I use vector<T> in template, I should manually implement destructor no matter what type T is?

Comment: What I meant is that you should not use a vector. A vector variable only contains the _bookkeeping_ like the length of the vector and where the memory is allocated on the heap. Vector elements are therefore not in the location of the vector variable itself. So  `xyz.x` and `xyz.y` _do not_ correspond with elements 0 and 1 of the vector.  However, writing to any element of `xyz` does overwrite the bookkeeping of the vector as they coincide with the vector variable itself. This leads to memory leaks and writing to or reading from arbitrary memory locations (and program abortions).